# 'messageCreate' keeps firing when an image is attached to the message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  var findChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "temp-channel");

  if(message.channel === findChannel) {
    if(message.attachments.size > 0) {
      var playerPoints = db.get(`${message.author.id}_points`);
      if (!playerPoints) {
        db.set(`${message.author.id}_points`, 1);
      } else {
        db.add(`${message.author.id}_points`, 1);
      }
      message.reply(`**+1 Game Point**, you now have **${db.get(`${message.author.id}_points`)}** points`)
    }
  }
})
```

For the most part, it works. But the issue is when a message is sent with an image, it repeatedly replies to the message author non-stop. What have I done wrong here?

I've been on discord.js v12 for years, but v13 changed too much..

I have tried numerous ways to attempt to stop the bot from repeatedly replying to the author, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't really see any error in the code, asides from more optimisation that you can do. The code doesn't have any looping, unless if you are running multiple instances or if someone is spamming messages. A code suggestion would be to remove `if(message.author.id === client.user.id) return;` as you've already checked if the user sending a message is a bot, therefore there is no need for that, unless if you are selfbotting.

Comment: Interesting. I could have sworn I have done something wrong... It just keeps firing the event when the bot replies to the message and just infinitely replies to the message with the response I implemented. I guess it's just replit haha. Thanks. I'll look into it :)

Comment: Maybe your if statement is wrong, `if(message.channel.id == findChannel.id && message.attachments.size > 0) { }`

Comment: @Lemaaa I LOVE YOU SO MUCH. IT WORKS LMAOAOAO thanks hahah.

Comment: @Lemaaa that really shouldn't be causing a complete loop though, it'll only trigger a wrong output but wouldn't cause repeated outputs wouldn't it?